# How to save TF IDF vectorizer with custom tokenizer? python

Tags: python, databricks, pickle, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to save my tf idf vectorizer with pickle, but unfortunatelly i keep getting an error

```
Can't pickle local object 'preprocess.<locals>.my_tokenizer'
```

This is the vectorizer where my tokenizer is my custom tokenizer :

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer= my_tokenizer, 
  ngram_range=(1,3), min_df=0.005, max_df=0.2)
```

This is the pickle

```
import pickle
with open('vectorizer.game', 'wb') as fin:
      pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, fin)
```

I do not know how to make it global

Answer (score 0):

‌before loading the vectorizer you need to add your custom tokenizer (my_tokenizer).
copy the code or import it